# Return all matching string collection from regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find out all browser name with version using regex in c#. But it is returing only one string.

```
var browsers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
browsers.Add("Chrome", @"Chrome\/(\S+)");
foreach(var browser in browsers)
{
    var browserRegex = new Regex(browser.Value);
    var result  = browserRegex.Matches(userAgent);
    //result.Groups
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        var versionRegex = new Regex(@"[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){0,2}");
        var version = versionRegex.Matches(result[1].ToString())[0];
        return browser.Key + " " + version.ToString();
    }
}
```

result should contain two string

- Chrome/68.0.3440...
- 68.0.3440...

But `result` contains only single string

- Chrome/68.0.3440...

My User Agen Value is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396...`

Comment: You are matching one pattern, hence you get one match.  What is surprising about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to grab 1, 2 or 3 dot-separated numbers after `Chrome/` substring.

Use

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"Chrome/(\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2})");
if (m.Success) 
{
    return $"Chrome {m.Groups[1].Value}";
} // else...
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Chrome%2F%28%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%7B0%2C2%7D%29&i=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F67.0.3396).

Here, `Chrome/(\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2})` will match `Chrome/` and then will capture into Group 1 (later referred to with `m.Groups[1].Value`) one or more digits (`\d+`) and then zero to two occurrences of a `.` (`\.`) followed with 1+ digits.

Comment: Loved the demo tool its helps in quick testing of the expression

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Well, for a *quick* testing, you might even use http://regex101.com, but it does not support .NET regex syntax. If you know how .NET regex differs from those supported by regex101, you may use that one, too, since it also explains the patterns. To get a similar experience, there is a free Ultrapico Expresso tool (no affiliation).

Comment: Well, the pattern can be extended like this: [`(Mozilla|Chrome)/(\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28Mozilla%7cChrome%29%2f%28%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%7b0%2c2%7d%29&i=Mozilla%2f5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3b+Win64%3b+x64%29+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+%28KHTML%2c+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2f67.0.3396) => `var ms = Regex.Matches(s, @"(Mozilla|Chrome)/(\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2})"); foreach (Match m in ms) { Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value); Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value); }`